# Windows 10 Mobile (Lumia 950 XL) + Mercedes Comand internet connection

Tags: bluetooth, internet-sharing, lumia-950-xl

Situation: a Mercedes car and Lumia 950 XL with Windows 10 Mobile. Normally it should be possible to browse the web via the Mercedes Comand using the internet connection of the smartphone via bluetooth.

However I can't seem to get it working when I set up a mobile hotspot on my smartphone. Can anyone help?

Comment: I have the same problem. I gave already feedback via windows feedback app. No problem with my Lumia 920 (Windows Phone 8.1) and Samsung Galaxy S6

Comment: @MarcelJanus can you tell me the steps that you are using (what do you enable in the Phone or what would be needed to enable to make it work?)